# Angular.js (1.6.9) conditonally apply class using $eval

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angular1.6

I am trying to use ng-class to apply conditional formatting within an ng-repeat. The condition should be based on evaluation of an object data string.

I am trying to get his code to apply bold to the 3rd item. I have done my best at trying `$eval` or `$parse` to no avail.

```
  <body ng-app="examsApp">
    <div ng-controller="ExamsController as examsList">
      <div ng-repeat="exam in examsList.exams">
        <span ng-repeat="levelnum in exam.levels.levelnums" ng-class="{ 'bold': $eval(exam.levels.evalby[$index]) }">
          {{levelnum}}
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>


var data = [
    {
        "id": "exam1",
        "text": "Exam 1",
        "levels":
            {
                "levelnums": ['2', '3', '4', '5'],
                "evalby": ['$scope.bold === 0', '$scope.bold ==== 1', '$scope.bold === 2', '$scope.bold === 3']
            }
    }
]

angular.module('examsApp', [])
    .controller('ExamsController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        var examsList = this;
        examsList.exams = data;

        $scope.bold = 2;
}])
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IaVkPqvMPsLPP1xhCUe1?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plunk has a handful of small issues, two of which can be found by opening the developer console:

1. You're not including `angularJS`.
2. You are trying to `ng-repeat` over `examsList.exams` outside of the `div` that is assigned the `examList` `controller`.
3. You have an extra ')' at the end of your last value in the `eval` array.
4. All of your rules in the `eval` array currently resolve to `false`.
5. You don't have a `css` rule for the `bold` class defined.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HqNl2Tqau55HXdWS3dVz?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. I had missed a save on plunkr seemingly for all of these issues. I am not sure why I wasn't working other than that, but your answer is correct.